# Name of dance style from Robin Hood: Men in Tights?

Tags: robin-hood-men-in-tights

Does anyone know the name of the dance style shown in Robin Hood: Men in Tights? It's the scene where they're singing the "we're men. We're men in tights" song, but specifically the portion where they are singing "na, nana nana na na" and they are kicking out their legs in unison.

Is there a formal/common name for that leg kicking dance? "Hey guys let's do the ________ dance?"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is called the Can-can.

> The can-can (or cancan as in the original French; French pronunciation: ​[kɑ̃kɑ̃]) is a high-energy, physically demanding dance that became a popular music hall dance in the 1840s, continuing in popularity in French cabaret to this day.[1] Originally danced by both sexes, it is now traditionally associated with a chorus line of female dancers.[2] The main features of the dance are the vigorous manipulation of skirts and petticoats, along with high kicks, splits, and cartwheels.

The music that they are singing at this point is also the traditional music from that dance.

Source: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Can-can